# With scientific notation, two different floats evaluate as equal

Tags: python

How come the following expression evaluates to true?

```
In [0]: 1e18 == (1e18 + 50)
Out[0]: True
```

When replacing the scientific notation by exponentiation, this evaluates, as one would expected, to `False`:

```
In [1]: 10**18 == (10**18 + 50)
Out[1]: False
```

Comment: It's the difference between (multiple-precision) integer arithmetic - and computer floating point.  'e' notation gives you floating point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do *not* have two pairs of floats.  The top example, being scientific notation, is a pair of floats.  Since the added difference is less than float precision, they compare as equal.

The bottom example is a pair of integers.  You can easily check this with the `type` function.  Python's long integers have no problem keeping the needed 18 digits of accuracy.

```
>>> type(1e18)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(10**18)
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to add a `.` to make the second expression floats. This makes total sense, thank you!